# .Net using html tags in label for model display attributes

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to create an HTML form based on various fields that I display in a contact form model. However, within the `label` attribute for a field I want to use some HTML tags such as `<strong>` and `<span>` to distinguish parts of the `label`, i.e. the HTML I am aiming for is:

```
<label for="error">
     <strong>Error</strong>  
     - Has the app stopped working?
     <span class="small">Did the app crash whilst running?</span>
</label>
```

When I do it using the model/view approach. I declare a field in the model and give it a name display attribute, and in the view the label method picks up this name attribute. But I cant see a way to add the extra HTML (i.e. the `<span class="small">Did the app crash whilst running?</span>` bit)
Here is the code I have:

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Has the app stopped working?")]
public string Error{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Error, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Error, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "email form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Error, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I cannot seem to add HTML in the `name` attribute and it seems messy this way too - is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Just add the HTML in your view. Don't use the helper method

Comment: The HtmlHelpers encode the output so you need to do this manually